# Flutter - TextFormfield is taking too much padding/extra space in UI/How to make label text the same size when it is active/inactive

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, user-interface

As you can see in the UI, when I am using text and textformfield in column, the space between Mobile number and TextFormField is too much -

[image]

I am making a UI, in which I want things to be like this -

[image]

So I used two different approaches. First, I used label in the TextFormField, but whenever TextFormField is not active, it look like this -

[image]

And when it is active, it looks perfectly as I want -

[image]

So, how can I achieve this, that whenever the field is not active, it should still look like this with label text or how to reduce the padding to remove the white space when using a column with text and textfield as the children.

Refer to the code here -

```
class HelpPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Help'),
          backgroundColor: colorPrimary,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'PNR/Booking Id',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: popUpLightTextColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'AWP80A',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Seats',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: popUpLightTextColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'UD8',
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 1.0,
                width: double.infinity, //MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.grey[300],
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Origin',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: popUpLightTextColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'New Delhi',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Destination',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: popUpLightTextColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Mathura',
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 1.0,
                width: double.infinity, //MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.grey[300],
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Name*',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: popUpLightTextColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Kirti Agarwal',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 1.0,
                width: double.infinity, //MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.grey[300],
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.7,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    /*Text(
                      'Mobile Number*',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: popUpLightTextColor,
                      ),
                    ),*/
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        label: Text('Mobile Number*', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20),)
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 17,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 1.0,
                width: double.infinity, //MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.grey[300],
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Origin',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: popUpLightTextColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'New Delhi',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Destination',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: popUpLightTextColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Mathura',
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 1.0,
                width: double.infinity, //MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.grey[300],
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Origin',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: popUpLightTextColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'New Delhi',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Destination',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: popUpLightTextColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Mathura',
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 1.0,
                width: double.infinity, //MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.grey[300],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with content padding textformfield content padding

```
TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5), // adjust as you need 
                          label: Text('Mobile Number*', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20),)
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 17,
                      ),
                    ),
```

output:

[image]